# Is there a word meaning neither a source nor a sink?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

When describing vector fields you may come across sources and sinks... but I am wondering if there is a word to describe any point which is neither a source nor a sink?

I actually want this for use in an analogy to describe something in economics and it would just make my argument sound stronger if I had a word for the non-source-sink thing.

Comment: Do you mean a fixed point that is neither a source nor a sink, i.e., a saddle point? Or do you mean non-fixed points? In which case, maybe just 'non-fixed' is enough? Maybe also 'non-singular'.

Comment: *Anything* that's not a source or a sink? Or specifically an equilibrium/fixed point that's not a source or a sink? (Or another word for "non-equilibrium"?)

Comment: I mean *any* point that is neither a source nor sink.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying; please edit that into your question.  Unfortunately, I doubt you're going to find one because sources and sinks are only *some* of the ways for fixed points in a vector field to be special, and it wouldn't be too useful to have a word that lumps in all of those with points that aren't even fixed points.